# Align Application Bar buttons

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible align/rearrange Application Bar buttons on Windows Phone 7?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, unless you develop your own control that mimics its behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is something you should want.

The application bar is a control that looks and feels the same in all windows phone applications. Because of this users have a  a much better experience using your app because they are familiar with all the controls you use in your applition.

There are a lot of conventions like this you should just follow which makes your app so much better.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button image that is all transparent then add that button and disable it where you want the gap.

Edit to add: That gives you the empty space that you showed in your suggested layout but you can't do any more than that.